# Why don't default nested Polymer values work?

Tags: polymer

I am using the latest `2.0-preview` version of Polymer. I'd like to set default properties, and the Polymer documentation describes [how to do it in Polymer 1.x](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#configure-values). I was unable to find any changes in this approach for [v2.0](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade). But it seems to only work for primitive properties and not objects:

```
"use strict";

class NewElement extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() {
        return 'new-element';
    }

    static get config() {
        return {
            properties: {
                user: {
                    // type: Object,  <-- doesn't help anyway

                    firstName: {
                        type: String,
                        value: "John",
                        // observer: '_callObserver'  <-- FYI observers don't work properly too if this usage...
                    },

                    lastName: {
                        type: String,
                        value: "Doe"
                    }
                },
                position: {
                    type: String,
                    value: "Waiter"  // <-- will set a high-level default value properly correctly
                }
            },

            // observers: [
            //    '_callObserver(user.*)'  <-- ...but works using this approach
            // ]
        }
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        console.dir(this); //  <-- see screenshots below
        // this.user = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" };  <-- works if initialized manually
    }
}

customElements.define(NewElement.is, NewElement);
```

As you can see [here](http://prnt.sc/dqij10) there is a getter, and when I click on it, I see that [`user` field is undefined](http://prnt.sc/dqiiga).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to nest property declarations, which is not supported. You can declare an object property that contains subproperties (not property declarations that have `type`, `observer`, etc.).

The `user` property declaration:

```
properties: {
  user: {
    type: Object,
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      value: "John",
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      value: "Doe"
    }
  },
},
```

should actually look like this:

```
properties: {
  user: {
    type: Object,
    value: function() {
      return {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe"
      };
    }
  },
},
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/egOLNW?editors=1010)

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you! I'm trying to understand how to work with Polymer data system, and it seems I would need nested property declarations when creating a complex application. May be you know - is this the potential problem or not? Have Polymer any plans to support these declarations?

Comment: @SergeyNovikov No problem :) As far as I'm aware, there are no plans for that. But what are you trying to do? If you want to observe subproperties, that's already possible with [complex observers](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#complex-observers) (e.g., `observers: ['_firstNameChanged(user.firstName)']`).

Comment: Also, note the [Data system concepts](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system) docs might be generally useful to read (in case you haven't already seen it).

Comment: Yes, I was trying to add observers to nested props and firstly I tried to add it the same way as for high-level props. Now I see that `observers:[...]` very useful so I don't know now for what I would need this functionality. Thanks :)